# Constraint width child UL of a LI in a dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to constrain the width of an `<ul>` tag in a dropdown menu in CSS to the width of the parent `<li>`of that `<ul>` in the simpliest possible form, and without setting any fixed with.

I had made a lot search and testing, without achieving it or understand it. Precisely, I want to understand how it works.

What could the property that could make it happened ?

I have settled the simpliest jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zAXRK/2/ I could come up with to see if someone could explain why if it's possible, and how ?

I you try the example, when you use the cursor to over the First Item = the sub-menu appears and the `<li>`who contains it, is going larger, pushing other elements.

What I want to do is making the sub-menu inside the width of its parent element, whatever the width, and without fixing it. (if there is no solution, I'll do it with JS, but I would prefer have it clean in CSS and I think this a good exercice).

Thanks to anyone willing to help me understand CSS rules. If the answer is somewhere outside, either I didn't find it, or I didn't understood it, please forgive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set some `position` properties on the `li` and the `.submenu` so you can set a `width: 100%` (it's not a fixed width, I hope it's not a problem):

Here are the changes :

```
.menu > li {
    position: relative;
} 

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/zAXRK/3/).

Comment: Wonderful, it's the absolute positionning that change the behavior and stop pushing the parent ( I don't even need the `width: 100%` as the `<ul>` element has `display: block` ). Thanks a lot.